# How to set starting index in split command in linux ?

Tags: linux, file, unix, split

I wanted to split a large file into multiple files based on number of lines in linux. I read about `split` and `csplit`. These command provides an option to suffix the file with numeric value by making use of `-d` option like 
 `split -d -l 100 largeFile.txt smallFile.txt.` would create the small files with `smallFile.txt.00`,`smallFile.txt.01 ....` . But I wanted starting index to be `01` instead of `00` . `Man pages` does not give much information about that. So,  Kindly help me on this and 
Is there a better approach for splitting the file based on number of lines in linux?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Since coreutils release 8.16 (2012-03-26) you can do:

```
split --numeric=1 -l 100 largeFile.txt smallFile.txt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said Linux that means split comes from GNU coreutils. If you look at the source for split the code handling the -d / --numeric-suffixes option is setup to take an optional argument but the call to `getopt_long` does not enable one. Perhaps due to compatibility reasons? You should mail them and ask.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/split.c;hb=HEAD

```
@@ -1153,7 +1153,7 @@ main (int argc, char **argv)
       int this_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
       char *slash;

-      c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "0123456789C:a:b:del:n:u",
+      c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "0123456789C:a:b:d:el:n:u",
                        longopts, NULL);
       if (c == -1)
         break;
```

This patch enables the optional number argument to be handled. Then you can invoke split as:

```
split -d 1 foo foo.split.
```

And the numbers start from 1, not 0.

You can get the source from http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ and apply this change yourself and use it locally if you like.

Comment: We don't allow optional arguments to short options, due to the ambiguities it introduces. In this case just use the long option if you need to specify the starting point:

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it, so I went to the source. Probably had an older version of the split code on my system.